# What semantic notions underlie "durable; to endure" (耐) with "about 3 cm", "tiny" (寸)?

Tags: etymology

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%90) doesn't expound the semantic shift. Doesn't 寸 contradict 耐? Humans usually "endure" or "resist" what's hefty and strong, not objects that are "tiny" and merely "about 3 cm".

> **Etymologies**
>
> 「[耐](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%90)」本作「[耏](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%8F)」，古刑名，參見「[耏](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%8F)」。後引伸有忍、受之義。《廣韻》：「耐，忍也。」《荀子．仲尼》：「能耐任之，則慎行此道也。」

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%80%90) has the same etymology, but I quote [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E8%80%90) for it's trustworthier.

[image]

Comment: Did you actually read CUHK's explanation? It says that it is a 古刑名, the name of a kind of sentence (punishment) in the past. If you look at 耏, it tells you exactly what that sentence is. Now the "endure" meaning should make sense, right?

Comment: I think you should read CUHK's explanation of 寸. You're making a lot of assumptions on modern literal meanings, when that's not how character components work. As part of a character, if it is contributing meaning (not sound), 寸 means the same thing as 又.

Comment: Quote:- "Humans usually "endure" or "resist" what's hefty and strong, not objects that are "tiny" and merely "about 3 cm" Well, a bullet is less than 3 cm. Let's see some humans "endure" that, without a bullet-resistant vest of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「耐」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*nˤə-s/**, *minor punishment involving the shaving of a beard* > *to endure*) is comprised from doubly semantic and phonetic [「而」 (**/*nə/**, *picture of a beard*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=428), now written 「髵」) and semantic [「寸」 (*picture of a hand*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=48) > *actions of the hand*).

---

「寸」 rarely or never means *inch* as part of other characters - it is derived from [「又」 (*picture of a hand*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) with an additional mark pointing to this wrist area. As a stand-alone character, this meaning originally referred to *the area where the pulse is taken* (Chinese medicine: 寸口). As part of other characters, it plays the same meaning role as 「又」 (if it is used for meaning, not sound). Observe, for example,

- [Glyph origin of 「對」](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19346/what-is-the-origin-of-the-character-%e5%af%b9-%e5%b0%8d), compound of a *hand* 「寸」 packing *dirt* 「土」 using a tool 「丵」
- [Glyph origin of 「尊」](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/31115/18338) (*ceremonial wine vessel used in rites*), compound of simultaneously semantic and phonetic 「寸」 (*picture of a hand*) and semantic 「酋」 (*picture of a wine vessel*)
- [Glyph evolution table of 「得」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2089) (*to obtain*), originally semantic 「寸」 (*hand*) + semantic 「貝」 (*money*)
- [Glyph evolution of 「持」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1251) (*to hold, grasp*), originally semantic 「寸」 (*hand*) + phonetic 「」 (之)

Answer (score -1):

There is no complete explanation on this question. But we could follow some explanations in history and fill the missing links ourselves.

1. The original character of 耐 is 耏.
2. The original meaning is not related to 寸, and not "endure" either.
3. 而 is a pictorial word about facial hairs.

說文, a dictionary written in 100 CE, has an entry about 耏, i.e. "耏，罪不至髡也。从而从彡。". A longer version is written in 說文解字注, "耏，罪不至髡也。从而从彡。耐，或从寸。諸法度字从寸。". This means 耐 is a variant form of 耏.

耏 is a penalty of removing one's hairs beside ears. It is lighter penalty than 髡, i.e. removing all hairs. The sentence "諸法度字从寸" indicates that later 耐 replaced 耏 for the meaning in laws. We might speculate that 寸 is a kind of measurement and further relates it to laws. 耐 finally wins the favourite form in the long history.

The meaning of "endure" is derivative. We could make a guess that one bearing this penalty must bear some kinds of humiliation. This might be the reason it derives the meanings of "bear, endure, resist and patient".